# How to add image banner in github?

Tags: github, readme

I want to add an image banner that would be displayed when searching through the Github topics (since the repo stands out).

I want to do something like this[image]

currently, I'm adding the image at the top of the readme.md file but it does not work.

```html
<h1 align="center">
 <img src="image-url-here" />
</h1>

# rest of readme ..
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the ["Social Preview"](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/customizing-your-repositorys-social-media-preview) under your repository settings.

---

<strike>README.md is written in [Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/). It is then translated into HTML. The `md` is for "Markdown".</strike>

Your HTML would be written like so:

```
# [description of the image](image-url-here)
```

`#` indicates a first tier header and `![description of the image](image-url-here)` is a link to an image with the alt of "description of the image".

More help can be found in [Writing On GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github).

Comment: But how does the image appear as a thumbnail of the repository when searching by topic? (as shown in the screenshot). The example in the question does not seem to have that image in the README.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Found it. "Social Media Preview"

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about this.

Answer (score 4):

- Simply go to the repo settings

[image: repo settings]

- Then under **Social preview** click on **Edit** and upload your banner.

[image: social preview]